# CloudByte Elasticenter fails to create pool, "add file /etc/disablescsi"

Tags: virtualbox

When I try to create pool in elastistor using elasticenter it gives the scsi error. How do I fixit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using virtual box then make sure that your os is under SCSI controller and not ide controller. To check go to Settings>storage>right click to add scsi controller and install your os under it.

At elastistor OS run this command to `touch /etc/disablescsi` or create the file disablescsi in etc directory and save it.

This should resolve the problem.

If you are not on virtualbox then you might want to contact coud support